# C# asp.net How do I store the month-end balance of a savings account and display in the chart

Tags: c#

I am currently doing a project in school and I wanted to store the month-end balance of an account and then display it on a chart - for example, the `X` axis is the month and the `Y` axis is the balance at the end of the month - but I'm not sure how to do it.

For example, how do I store data on which balance belongs to which month? I've been having trouble finding relevant information on the Internet.

I am new to C# and currently using VS 2013. I'm really thankful if anyone can help me! (I have 4 days left until my final presentation).

Comment: Well is a school project , so actually we r doing a banking website .  And everybody is given different task . So I am doing the account part. And i actually have no idea of how to store it. I am thinking of if I can make use of transactions . (But it only stores the debit amount so maybe I can do a month expenses graph instead  ? )

Comment: Is a relational database ok storage-wise? What's your back-end by the way (ASP.NET, PHP, Ruby on Rails...)?

Comment: ya, using the SQL server in the visual studio. is c# asp.net

Comment: Break your problem down and the attempt each part.  Nobody will write a full solution for you.

Comment: Is the part you're having trouble with the table design? What have you tried so far, and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: i am having problem on how should I get the balance of the user on the specific date (last day of the month) then i store this balance into the respective month and then display in a chart

Comment: @DarrenYoung well, i know i cannt be having people to write the full solution for me . so i am trying to find the algorithm of how should do in order to get what i want

Comment: Have an `Account` object with a datetime for the date and double/decimal for balance. Then write it off to the db.

Comment: What does your data look like? What information are you given about the accounts, transactions, etc. that you can use to solve it? Are you given enough information to solve the problem? Think about how you'd do the calculation "by hand" given the same information.

Comment: By the way, are you using ASP.NET Webforms or MVC?

Comment: ok i have tables such as,  Customer:username and other details of the user. Account table: account number and the balance of the account. Then a transaction table where, store the transaction amount and the date of transaction. this are some relevant tables. then for the monthly balance , i have no idea of how to store. i am really thankful that u r trying to help me. @EJoshuaS

Comment: @EJoshuaS is webform

Comment: Do you already have a calculation for the monthly balance? Is the issue how to calculate the monthly balance in the first place, how to store the calculation results once you have them, or how to display them on your front end? ASP.NET has some articles on how to create ASP.NET charts here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx

Comment: @EJoshuaS i have no problem in doing CRUD or having specific user to login. but i am stuck at the logic of how to get the balance of the last day of the month and store into the specific month . is it i need to keep track of the balance everyday? can i like compare the datetime when they first login and if the datetime is the lastday of the month, i store the balance? but how do i know is which month ? i am really sorry cause i am really new to c# and i really want to get what i want .

Comment: @EJoshuaS ya i dk how to calculate the monthly balance at the first place . when all i have is just a single balance referring  to different user in the database. and also even i get the balance , how should i store

Comment: Is the database balance the daily balance? If that's the case, then, the question would be "given today's balance and a record of the transactions, how do I know what the balance was at the end of each month?" (Try not to think about the problems in terms of C# yet - think about how you'd do the same thing "by hand" so you know what the algorithm is and then think about how to write that algorithm in C#).

Comment: Is it I need to store the beginning Balance of the month . And then minus/plus the transactions when it is  the last day of the month ?

Comment: If you have the daily balance you could always just capture it at the end of the month. (Since you have a Windows server anyway just use the task scheduler). No need to compute it.

Comment: You could also use a SQL Server job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the month-end balance for a user, capture the daily balance on the last day of the month with a SQL Server job or a small script or program that you run on your server with Windows Task Scheduler.

In principal you could also calculate the balance for any arbitrary day based on the transactions that occurred. For example, if I know that today's balance is $1000, that I want last Wednesday's balance, and I know that the following transactions took place:
7/28 $-25 (gas)
7/28 $-10 (lunch out)
7/29 $+250 (paycheck)
7/30 $-15 (book purchase
then I know that last Wednesday's balance has to be 1000 - 250 + 15 + 10 + 25 = **$800**. The major downside to this is that it could be computationally expensive if you're calculating the balance for the very distant past, if you're doing this computation regularly (e.g. if you have to do it every single time the user pulls up their history), or if there are lots of users.

In terms of the front-end UI, there are good instructions on charting here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx

Comment: Thank you !!! Actually I don quite understand the use of window task scheduler . Do u have any examples ? So there is no way for me to use back end  code to achieve what I want?

Comment: Basically, if you went this route, you'd have a small executable SomeProgram.exe that would do nothing but go to the database, retrieve the current balance for each user, and insert it as the current month's ending balance. You'd then schedule SomeProgram.exe to run on the last day of the month. (You don't particularly care if the last day of the month is a business day or not; if it isn't the balance should be the same as it was on the last business day).

Comment: Can I do this using the visual studio itself ?? Cause I am afraid my school don allow us to install other programs . If is possible can give me an example . Thank you !!!!

Comment: Yes, the program can be in C# or whatever. Which part are you looking for an example of?

Comment: @EjoshaS like how do I implement the programme ?? any way thanks for your help!!!  now i am able to just do a monthly expenses graph. so if I cannot do the month end balance i will stay with this plan

Comment: The program itself is pretty straightforward - you use classes from System.Data.SqlClient to connect to your database (see an example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx#_SqlClient). For the SQL statement itself, you'll probably want to do something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp - all the program (or SQL Server job) will actually do is execute this query to copy the current balance into this month's balance.